# How to open google map externally from phonegap app

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have opening google map app from  my phonegap by

```
<a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=Bengaluru, Karnataka&daddr=Chennai, Tamil Nadu" data-rel="external"><img src="img/ico_pin.png" />White House</a>
```

Here, Google map opens phonegap gap itself. Here, i did some functionality in back button. So it will affect to google map app also.

So , i want to open google map app externally from phonegap app

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this without using any plugin..

```
    if (device.platform.toUpperCase() === 'ANDROID') {
       navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal: true });
    }
    else if (device.platform.toUpperCase() === 'IOS') {
        window.open(url, '_system');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open native Google Maps from the Phonegap app like below.

```
<a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">open map</a>
```

**Phonegap direction Plugin**

You need to use [plugin](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/External-Service) for directions

**Sample Code**

```
plugin.google.maps.external.launchNavigation({
  "from": "Tokyo, Japan",
  "to": "Kyoto, Japan"
});
```

It will open native Google Maps

Comment: I tried this.I doesn't work for me. When i click on this, There is no event here

Comment: `There is no event here` what do you mean by that ?

Comment: It will open google map. But i want direction on map. i have mentioned source and destination in above my ques. So i want like that

Comment: Thanks, I dont want to use plugin for this one. Already i have using this one <a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=Bengaluru, Karnataka&daddr=Chennai, Tamil Nadu" data-rel="external"><img src="img/ico_pin.png" />White House</a>. Here getting direction but it will open same app itself. I want it open at externally